# How to make a button that will redirect to a webpage after some word inserted?

Tags: javascript, html, button, search, input

I plan on making a search website, but don't know how to make something like:
A user inserts something in the search box
After clicking "Search", gets redirected to a website like, duckduckgo.com/?q=text inserted in the search box

Thanks,
Doge

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Explain more. Add some of your code. You must show us that you are trying yourself and that you are coding. This is not a platform to find solutions only. This is a platform to ask for help, and in order to get a better results you must give us a sample of your code at least

Answer (score 0):

This should work: 
`window.location.replace("duckduckgo.com/?q=" + string);`

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet I created an input field and a button.
If you type "asd" to the input field and click the "Search" button, you're gonna be redirected to: http://duckduckgo.com/?q=asd

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" /> 
    <button>Search</button>

    <script>
      let button = document.querySelector('button');
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let inputValue = document.querySelector('input').value;
        let redirectToUrl = 'http://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + inputValue;
        window.location.replace(redirectToUrl);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using Javascript

You must use: `window.location.href`, and make sure that the website you are redirecting to starts with `http://` or `https://`

window.location.href = "http://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + text;

> Using "form" in HTML

You must put the `<input>` field in a `<form>` and target the form to the url you with to, and make sure that is is a GET request.

```
<form method='get' action='http://duckduckgo.com'>
    <input type='text' name='q' value='' />
    <input type'button' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Once you click on submit, you will be redirected to the page `http://duckduckgo.com?q={input text}`

```js
$("#jsBloc a").click(function() {
  window.location.href = "http://duckduckgo.com?q=" + $("#jsBloc").val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Using Javascript: </h1>
<div id='jsBloc'>
    <input type='text' name='q' value='' />
    <a href='javascript:;'>Submit</a>
<div>

<hr />

<h1>Using Form HTML</h1>
<form method='get' action='http://duckduckgo.com'>
    <input type='text' name='q' value='' />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: He is not using JavaScript if he has the form you quoted, is he?

Comment: I don't really know. He didn't put any code samples. But he did added Javascript and HTML tags in the question, so I gave him answers for both